# detect VGA port (through pinout) and send a command to microcontroller

Tags: arduino, pinout, vga, port

How can i realize that a video project is connected to laptop through a VGA port??
I think I can understand it from the VGA pinout; but i don't know which one??
If I realize it then I can send a command to microcontroller and then do some functions...

Answer (score 2):

Which "side" are you on - the monitor side or the driving side?

Either way round the magic words are ["EDID"](http://www.extron.com/company/article.aspx?id=uedid) and ["VESA DDC"](http://www.chrisbot.com/i2c-and-monitor-ddc.html). The protocol is basically I2C. Monitors will return a list of supported resolutions and timings.

Comment: +1. If this is a linux laptop then the I2C bus can be interrogated directly using the device nodes, or there are several free tools available that will read the contents at the VDU's address space.  If Windows, then I believe the equivalent can be done via a powershell script.

Answer (score 1):

> project is connected to laptop through a VGA port

You seem to be building displaying device. Then you detect connection by seeing if there're horizontal and/or vertical sync signals.

Some monitors will not get out of sleep if there's no defined level on SCL and ID0 lines, you may sense them, if they at some time become ground, it's time to turn your display device on (this is actually simplified treatment of Vesa DDC - see pjc50's answer).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to VESA DDC, you can find out that a VGA display is connected (and which one) by examining pins 4, 11 and 12 of the connector:

```
ID pins set-up

4    11   12
ID2  ID0  ID1

n/c  n/c  n/c   no monitor
n/c  n/c  GND   Mono monitor which does not support 1024x768
n/c  GND  n/c   Color monitor which does not support 1024x768
GND  GND  n/c   Color monitor which supports 1024x768
```

Practically all modern displays will be in the last category, pulling pins 4 and 11 low.